# How can I read images in Kaggle with Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working in a analysis of data mining. I'm working with images from Kaggle, in a notebook in it. I have the root of this images given by .jpeg.

How can I read them? Then, I have to use this function `tf.keras.preprocessing` to get the variable and use it in a CNN model in Keras.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked using [`keras`](https://keras.io/api/data_loading/image/), we can use :

```py
tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    validation_split=None,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False,
    **kwargs
)
```

However, if we want to have a look at some pictures first, we can use the PIL library to display it directly in the notebook like so :

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('path/image.jpg')
img
```

This nice [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) might help you even better (at least it helped me a lot).